# How to position element on the bottom of its container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

***major edits, please re-open***

Creating a page with `Bootstrap 2.3.2` that will later become a template for `Joomla 3.x`.
In the header, I have 6 elements. I was able to position them as shown below.

#### problem

is positioning the `nav-pills` section quite at the bottom of the container that has `image` as `background-image`.

- setting `margin-top` on the `.minimenu` container of the `nav-pills` does work, but relates it to the top. I'd like to relate it to the bottom.
- `vertical-align: bottom;` has been tried with no solution.

[image: draft of header]

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <p class="headtitle">This is the Headline on Top!</p>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="http://www.chris-nlp-hall.com/tmp/logo1.png" class="pull-left logo1" />
        <img src="http://www.chris-nlp-hall.com/tmp/logo2.png" class="pull-right logo2" />
        <div class="mininav">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Learn</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
p.headtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}
.header {
    background-image: url(http://www.chris-nlp-hall.com/tmp/center.png);
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 160px;
}
.mininav {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom; /* doesn't work */
}
.mininav .nav-pills {
    display: inline-block;
}
.header .logo1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.header .logo2 {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

see this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/michi001/srzwz8o4/

Comment: Could you update your fiddle as well please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.header {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(http://www.chris-nlp-hall.com/tmp/center.png);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 160px;
}

.mininav {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Added relative postion in `.header` and modified `.mininav` class

I have fixed your issue [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayedrafeeq/srzwz8o4/2/)

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap you can use `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes for the logos and navpills can be centered using `text-center` class in a parent div.
Best option for the background seem to be place it via CSS using `background-image`.

Answer (score 1):

Then why don't you just position `absolute` to the bottom?

```
.mininav{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

you will also need to set `.header` as relative:

```
.header { position:relative; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.mininav {
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
min-height: 30px; /*or other value*/
max-height: 30px; /*or other value*/ 
position: absolute;
}

.mininav p {
line-height: 30px;
}
```